# how to query CouchDB array

Tags: arrays, couchdb

Our CouchDB contains many JSON documents with a nested Array, like this:

```
{ "_id": "3147cb0e74449e1c28c6ded2b4a3fa45e0d65481bd_RXMARTINEZ@miscemail.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z",
 "_rev": "3-99aef1458fe1a8f310c83156b9d06a69",
"delivery": {
 "application": "EnvSystem",
 "sender": {
  "id": "RXMARTINEZ@miscemail.com",
  "type": "user"
 },
 "recipients": [
  {"type": "email",
   "recipient": "\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@miscemail.com>",
   "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.515Z",
   "id": "45281ab0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"},
  {"type": "email",
   "recipient": "\"Hill, Robert V\" <RVHill@miscemail.com>",
   "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.516Z",
   "id": "452841c0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"},
  {"type": "email",
   "recipient": "\"Ledesma, Oscar\" <OLedesma@miscemail.com>",
   "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.516Z",
   "id": "452841c1-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"}
```

]

I have written a view which returns the entire array:
`emit(doc.delivery.recipients,1)`

what I want is to only return the "sentTS" element within the array.  How do I write my View do accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this map function if you want to emit the startTS as the key array

```
function (doc) {
  ts = [];
  doc.delivery.recipients.forEach(function(e){ts.push(e.sentTS)});
  emit(ts,1);
}
```

or this if you want to emit a key for each sentTS

```
function (doc) {
 doc.delivery.recipients.forEach(function(e){emit(e.sentTS)});
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  These both seem to work and give me VERY close to what I am looking for.  However, I do not fully understand the code; can you explain how these work?

Comment: forEach just iterate over recipients array and apply a function for extracting sentTS attribute of each array element.